# The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it + django

Tags: python, django, url, urlconf

I have been trying out the django tutorial and stuck with this error. I am in the 3rd page of the tutorial and everything was going good until i encountered this error [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/). I was following the exact steps in the tutorial. This is the error i got

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /polls
The included urlconf <module 'polls.urls' from 'C:\\Python34\\mysite\\polls\\urls.py'> doesn't have any patterns in it
```

I am pasting my code here.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'` in settings.py, 
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from polls import views

urlpattern = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
)`
```

inside MYSITE/POLLS/URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

INSIDE MYSITE.URLS.PY

Sorry if i missed out anything that i had to mention to get a clear picture. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first file has `urlpattern` instead of `urlpatterns`.

Comment: Thanks heaps Daniel..! that helped me ..!